# Signal Processing with Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

i just started a course "Introduction to signal processing with Matlab" and i came across with this task but i don't understand how is this possible. The task ask us to create a high frequency noise signal using an FIR-filter. But the FIR-filters are made to "clear" the noise from a signal. How can you do that?

Comment: “But the FIR-filters are made to "clear" the noise from a signal.” This is not true. Some FIR filters are low-pass filters, which have the effect of reducing noise (as well as fine detail). But some FIR filters are band-pass or band-suppress filters, some are high-pass filters, some are interpolating filters, some are derivative filters, some are shift filters, etc, etc, etc. You are looking for a high-pass filter.

Answer (score 1):

Filters applied in the frequency domain filter out certain frequencies based on the type of filter. It is not like FIR filters are used just to create high-frequency noise. But they can be used for this purpose also. For example, if you start with a white noise (that has all the frequencies), and then apply a high pass filter, the lower frequencies will be gone, and you will achieve a high-frequency noise signal. Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

for example a white-noise include all frequecies, so you can filter and clear low frq. noise with a high pass filter then you have a noise with only hagh freq.